# What are the correct folder permissions for Tomcat folders?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat

In my Amazon Linux instance, I had to grant `bin` and `libs` tomcat folders the permission 777 via `chmod 777 foldername`. But now I need to revert them back. What are the correct permission commands to make them as they were?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to "[Security Considerations](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/security-howto.html#Non-Tomcat_settings)" chapter in Tomcat Documentation (the link is for Tomcat 9.0). Definitely not world-writable. Usually not world-readable (especially the `conf` and `logs` directories). The rest depends on your requirements.

E.g. it may be `750` for all directories except the `conf` one and `700` for `conf`.